# Application variable got reset after session end

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to insert a visitor counter in my ASP site, so I've used a global.asax file to implement that. The problem is when the session ends the "AllVisitorCount" gets the default value which is set to 0 in my web.Config.

The code is:

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // Code that runs when a new session is started
  int allVisitorCount = 0;
  if (Application["AllVisitorCount"] != null)
    allVisitorCount = (int)(Application["AllVisitorCount"]);
  else
    Application.Add("AllVisitorCount", 0);
  allVisitorCount++;
  Application["AllVisitorCount"] = allVisitorCount;
}
```

Comment: This is what desirable, as the things you store in `Application` are session local. If you want the variables to live longer than the session, persist them to disc/database before sessions end, and load them back when sessions start.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you have slidingExpiration set to False in your web.config

Answer (score 1):

"Application" is not a permanent object. It is created once your application starts (e.g the first session is started) and disposes of after your application pool times out. You can either persist your variable or simply change "Idle time-out" parameter in your AppPool (IIS=>Application Pools => your AppPool (or DefaultAppPool if you haven't defined one)=> Advanced Settings => Idle Time-out).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your application pool is timing out with your session, thus clearing all Application variables.

Please provide more details such as: is this hosted in IIS, IIS Express, Cassini; how does the Session end (programmatically, timeout, etc.); have you placed a breakpoint on Application_End to see if the event is triggered.

Comment: thanks so much guys,i used Xml as the solution to implement the hit counter feature.i found it really useful for my case.